# Checking/unchecking buttons generated by a loop

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4

Buttons in my script are generated by a `for` loop, like that:

```
for number in xrange(1,5):
    self.btn = QPushButton(str(number))
    self.btn.setCheckable(True)
    self.btn.number = number
    self.h1box.addWidget(self.btn)
```

I want another button to be able to check/uncheck one of the buttons and I've got no idea how to do it, already googled so much about it, didn't help. I hope you won't kill me for that question.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for the "setChecked (self, bool)" function:
http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qabstractbutton.html#setChecked